# How to resolve java.lang.ClassCastException: hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have been class it has 5 fields and all are of type `String` in database(MySQL) the table corresponding to bean has 2 `varchar` type remaining 3 are `integer` type. I am performing simple insert operation through `session.save(obj)`. My Mapping file is as follow ,

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.aurodisplay.its.beans.VehicleRegisterBean"
    table="vehicle_details">
    <id column="vehicleno" name="vehicleno" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property column="vehicletype" name="vehicletype" type="java.lang.String"></property>
    <property column="model" name="model" type="java.lang.String"></property>
    <property column="clientid" name="clientid" type="java.lang.Integer"></property>
    <property column="groupid" name="groupid" type="java.lang.Integer"></property>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is my Java code snap

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

    // 2. create sessionfactory
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

    // 3. Get Session object
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    // 4. Starting Transaction
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    VehicleRegisterBean vehicleRegisterBean=new VehicleRegisterBean();


    vehicleRegisterBean.setVehicletype(request.getParameter("vehicletype"));    
    vehicleRegisterBean.setModel(request.getParameter("model"));
    vehicleRegisterBean.setVehicleno(request.getParameter("vehicleno"));

    vehicleRegisterBean.setClientid(request.getParameter("clientid"));
    vehicleRegisterBean.setGroupname(request.getParameter("groupname"));

     session.save(vehicleRegisterBean);
     transaction.commit();
     System.out.println("\n\n Details Added \n");
```

I am getting ClassCastException,

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.abc.its.controller.VehicleRegister] in context with path [/ITS_Server] threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.set(IntegerType.java:41)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:83)
at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:60)
at   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1947)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1924)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$1.bindValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2102)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:32)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2108)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2588)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:48)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:248)
```

I am new to hibernate, So can anyone help me to solve this .

Comment: Can you add your Jave code snap? Also here clientid and groupid is Intger while you are saying all are String ?

Comment: @Raghu `groupid, clientid, vehicleno` are your `Integer` fields.

Comment: yes . . those are integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem lies in these two lines:

```
vehicleRegisterBean.setClientid(request.getParameter("clientid"));
vehicleRegisterBean.setGroupname(request.getParameter("groupname"));
```

You are trying to cast String returned from request.getParameter to Integer values.

You need to convert the string values to Integer.

```
vehicleRegisterBean.setClientid(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("clientid")));
vehicleRegisterBean.setGroupname(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("groupname")));
```

**Note:** You may need to use variables to get the values from request and put in the null checks before converting to Integer.

Comment: every field in bean are string type , if we set int value, set method shows error.

Comment: @Raghu Then your bean definition in xml is not correct. Check these:     <property column="clientid" name="clientid" type="java.lang.Integer"></property>
    <property column="groupid" name="groupid" type="java.lang.Integer"></property>

Comment: @Raghu "every field in bean are string type" seems to be contradictory to your java bean  class and xml definition of bean.

Comment: now I am getting `org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value` what is this error

Comment: @Raghu The problem you have asked is actually answered. You need to figure out other problems by yourself or post new questions.

Answer (score 3):

change the code to something like this. Debug the code properly, and see which property actually is coming as instance of `java.lang.String`, ideally the root cause is it should come as Integer only.

But the workaround can be to parse it using

```
Integer.valueOf(String s);


vehicleRegisterBean.setVehicletype(request.getParameter("vehicletype"));    
vehicleRegisterBean.setModel(request.getParameter("model"));


vehicleRegisterBean.setVehicleno(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("vehicleno")));

vehicleRegisterBean.setClientid(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("clientid")));
vehicleRegisterBean.setGroupname(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("groupname")));
```

Well, the API for `Integer.valueOf(String)` does indeed say that the String is interpreted exactly as if it were given to `Integer.parseInt(String)`. However, `valueOf(String)` returns a `new Integer()` object whereas `parseInt(String)` returns a primitive int.

Now, if what you want is the object and not the primitive, then using `valueOf(String)`

**The database returned no natively generated identity value**

I think it means you're trying to use the k generator with a table column which is not properly configured. It should be an `auto_increment` column for the `IDENTITY` generator to work. Else, the database doesn't return any generated ID.

Better user `type = long`

```
<id column="vehicleno" name="vehicleno" type="java.lang.Integer">
         <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
```

Comment: every field in bean are string type , if we set int value, set method shows error.

Comment: I removed `generator ` tag it worked fine. Here I am taking `vehicleno` from UI, its not `autoincriment`.